# I want to use one JSON as template and use this template to keep only the matching elements from another data JSON, using java or groovy

Tags: java, groovy

Template JSON is below

```
{
    "id": "",
    "complex": {
        "nested": {
            "yawn": "",
            "even_more_nested": {
                "blah": ""
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Data JSON looks like this

```
{
    "id": "needed",
    "not_needed1": "not_needed",
    "complex": {
        "not_needed2": "not_needed",
        "nested": {
            "yawn": "needed",
            "not_needed4": "not_needed",
            "even_more_nested": {
                "blah": "needed"
            }
        },
        "not_needed3": "not_needed"
    }
}
```

Final JSON should look like this

```
{
    "id": "needed",
    "complex": {
        "nested": {
            "yawn": "needed",
            "even_more_nested": {
                "blah": "needed"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Are there any existing libraries that can do this? Or writing code is the only option? The template and the data JSON can be large, and an optimized library would be nice to have.

Comment: if you want json-to-json transformation with json template : https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt

Comment: You may use Jackson Json library, implement POJO(s) with the needed fields and configure ObjectMapper not to fail on unknown properties when reading data json.

Comment: @AlexRudenko This would mean I have to create a POJO first, which I would like to avoid as the JSON template can be a large one.